# postgresql - trigger function with update not working with initial insert

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to run a trigger each time a record is inserted or updated on table `knowledgebase_messages` which will vectorize the `message` column, using the joined pg_language_dictionary (e.g.: "French") for that message's locale_id.

Currently, the trigger working on row update, but not initial insert. Meaning, if I insert a row, then run a query to get records, updated the row in any way, or refresh the postgres UI, I see the vectorized value correctly there.

Trigger function:

```
  runMessageVectorTriggerFn = 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION run_message_vector() ' +
    'RETURNS TRIGGER ' +
    'AS $BODY$ ' +
      'BEGIN ' +
        'IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN ' +
           'RETURN NEW; ' +
        'END IF; ' +
        'UPDATE knowledgebase_messages kbm ' +
        'SET vector = to_tsvector(lang.pg_dictionary_name::regconfig, kbm.message) ' +
        'FROM locales as loca ' +
        'JOIN languages as lang ON loca.language_id = lang.id ' +
        'WHERE kbm.locale_id = loca.id;' +
        'RETURN NEW; ' +
      'END; ' +
    '$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql';
```

Trigger:

```
  runMessageVectorTrigger = 'CREATE TRIGGER run_message_vector AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON knowledgebase_messages ' +
    'FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE run_message_vector()';
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing this in the BEFORE INSERT trigger, it doesn't update
the row being inserted because the row doesn't exist yet:

```
UPDATE knowledgebase_messages kbm...
```

Besides, it's not clear what is the intention in your UPDATE because
the WHERE clause seems to ignore the `NEW` row, as if it was implicit
that it was the target.

Anyway, instead of that, to change the row being inserted/updated, do
something along the lines of:

```
-- the SELECT must return 1 row, or in the worst case no row
-- otherwise an error will occur.
NEW.vector = (
  SELECT
    to_tsvector(lang.pg_dictionary_name::regconfig, NEW.message)
  FROM locales as loca JOIN languages as lang
    ON loca.language_id = lang.id 
  WHERE NEW.locale_id = loca.id
);

RETURN NEW;
```

both in BEFORE UPDATE and BEFORE INSERT cases.

Then you can remove this `IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1...`

Comment: So how should my query structure look within `SELECT`? I'm not sure how to restructure the above